# Installing PPA:phablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am trying to set my desktop up to put Ubuntu on my phone but when I type in the command `sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb adroid-tools-fastboot` it just tells my that I have unmet dependencies

```
phablet-tools: depends: python-lzma but it is not installabe
               depends: python-requests but it is not installable
               recommends: ubuntu-dev-tools but it is not installable
```

Comment: The question is...?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do first add the PPA? from: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

For install missing deps

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```